# How can I make the file browser sort in ASCII order?

Tags: 16.04, sort, ascii

The so called "intelligent sorting" does not make any sense to me.
It will put 1z in front of 0005abz. I would like to have sorting order like it used to be:

00056
00056aaa
004abc
03abc
2abc

and not

2abc
03abc
004abc
00056aaa

Answer (score 0):

- This is by design: groups of digits are sorted in numeric order.

`/etc/default/locale` contains the defaults for this. Set `LC_COLLATE=C` in it. This will sort files alphabetical BUT be sure you know what you are doing: capitals and small letters are -not- next to each other in ASCII. Names starting with a capital will come 1st and then the files starting with a small letter.

ls though will now sort as numbers as `04, 0400, 1, 11, 2, 22, 3, 33`.